# .NET Core 2.0 performance profiling by Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, profiling, performance-testing

I use to profile my [.net framework] applications by Visual studio cpu profiler (Debug>Performance Profiler>CPU Usage) which profiles the performance and gives a detailed report:

[image: .Net Framework Example]

This tool also works for .net core, but the result is somewhat different and not user friendly for analyzing details.

For example when I examine the Call Tree view, the root node is dotnet.exe, which is expected. On the second level of the tree are all the called methods. But when I expand them I don't get the methods called by that methods, instead I see [coreclr.dll]. So I can't examine the hot lines by this method. See screenshot below:

[image: .Net Core Example]

I have tried also attaching to running process [iisexpress] instead of using Startup project option,  but the results are the same.

I wonder if there exists a better approach to get performance profiling result like it was in full framework?

I know there are some third party profilers for .net core, but I'd prefer to use Visual Studio if it may work.

**EDIT 1**: Added screenshots

**EDIT 2**
When enabling downloading symbols from Microsoft Symbol Server I get a bit different result, but not the expected. Instead of showing [coreclr.dll] it shows a bunch of .net core methods. But the problem persists:

[image]

If I implement methods A() and B(), and method A() calls method B(), then B won't be nested inside A node in the profiler report call tree. Instead A will have some children from coreclr.
I can't understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Does it download the debug symbols for .NET Core? If not try enabling the debug symbols server in Visual Studio (Options > Debugging > Symbols > Microsoft Symbol Server

Comment: I enabled that option. Now instead of showing [coreclr.dll] it shows a bunch of .net core methods. But the problem persists. I don't get the call tree with my methods nested in each other.

Comment: Mind updating with an example of what you are getting now? Maybe someone else has an idea :P There are also additional symbol sources for ASP.NET Core itself (iirc only .NET Core is on the Microsoft Symbol servers, have a look at this post which names two https://github.com/dotnet/home/issues/69#issuecomment-321912151)

Comment: I've updated my post. Thanks for the advise. But I don't thinks this is something related to debug symbols. I guess this is related to .net core architecture.

Comment: Are you running it in Debug mode? all the JIT thing sounds like some optimization was been done to it? i.e. disable the "optimize code" checkbox in .NET Standard/Core Projects properties?

Comment: I'm running in Debug build. And Optimize code checkbox is not checked

Comment: I get similar behavior. In the report, it says "No user code was running during the selected time range" which is very, very obviously false since I ran various tests against it.